# Integration problems with mixed HTTP / HTTPS website

Tags: jquery, http, https, cross-domain

I've been working on a webapp in my spare time.

It is largely oriented to publicly publishing/consuming content, so content is expected to be publicly viewable and over http.  It also allows-for/contains 3rd party widgets, so there is a need for http access (many vendors don't have https versions, and then there are mixed-content issues of http on https pages).  Because of this and some other business goals, 99% of the site must be available on http.

The lockdown scheme I have implemented so far is this:

- everything is on the same domain
- everything under /account & /api is handled via https and with https-only cookies. only these secure session ids can be used for writes or accessing personally-identifiable material.
- everything else is handled via http and, with a separate set of http cookies.  these cookies are largely for browser-based javascript customization, not for 'writes' or seeing sensitive content )

Which leads me to the problem...

If someone wants to perform a bookmarking or social activity on the webapp, it needs to happen through the HTTPS channel - using the HTTPS cookies, etc - however the same origin policy of browsers sees http and https as two distinct servers.

I'm trying to think of effective (and preferably simple) ways to allow for API calls to the HTTPS server from the HTTP content.  My first thought was to use JSONP, but I need the session cookie - and that's not visible to me.

Does anyone have some suggestions ?

Answer (score 3):

Let me try to understand your workflow: your HTTP page must call the HTTPS server, which in turn will access the session cookie, and you need the response to be accessible to the HTTP page, is that correct?

One way of doing that would be using a separate iframe to host the script that would communicate to the server, and have the main page and the iframe communicate using HTML5 [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage). So, the steps to realize the workflow above would be:

1. You use `postMessage` to the iframe, with the (serialized) request parameters;
2. The iframe's message callback receives the request, **confirms it comes from your page**, and submit an Ajax request to the server (passing the session cookie);
3. The response is received, serialized and sent to the main page using `postMessage`;
4. The main page's message callback receives the response and do something with it.

This should not be hard to encapsulate within a single function call. The tricky part here is the bold fragment above: if the script in the iframe does not properly confirm the request is coming from the right page this could create a CSRF vulnerability (a malicious page could embed your secure script in an iframe, send a request to it and, as long as the user is authenticated when that happens, the iframe would honor the request).

For that problem, unfortunatly there's little I can suggest. Embedding HTTPS content in HTTP pages is, overall, a bad idea, but since you have your reasons to do it you should deal with the security implications as well.